# How to automatically add a new property to an existing object by default in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In my program, I am expecting input from a form when the user fills it. And I want to collect the entries and append them / add them to an existing object/dictionary I already created in my script.js
**I tried using myObjectFile.newEntry = "James",**
but the problem is that it keeps replacing the previous entry name; newEntry, whenever a new input is created.
*Your help will be appreciated.*

For example,

```
myObjectFile.newEntry = 'James'
// myObjectFile is {...otherKey, newEntry: 'James' }
```

Now If I put

```
myObjectFile.newEntry = 'Harry';
// myObjectFile is {...otherKey, newEntry: 'Harry' }
```

What I expect is like this, `myObjectFile is {...otherKey, newEntry: ['James', 'Harry'] }`

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve] and someone will be happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

You question doesn't have any code example or expected results etc. But I would like to provide an answer here. From the description it seems to be working as expected. In an object, if you put some values against a key, it will replace the previous value. That is how object works. Like if you have an object like the following,

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2};
```

And then put some new values for `b` like this,

```
obj.b = 4;
```

The object will be like,

```
{a: 1, b: 4}
```

If you want to keep all values for a key, you have to use array for that key. Like this,

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: [2]};
```

And update your object like this,

```
obj.b = [...obj.b, 4];
```

Then the object will be like,

```
{a: 1, b: [2, 4]}
```

Instead of using simple integer values, you can use other objects as items of the array.